# Implementing abstract methods in a concrete class

Tags: java

I have coursework for my University project and I am struggling with the concept of abstract classes. I realise the reason for having them, to create sub-classes and I understand simple abstract class examples. The question is asking to implement a concrete class, Selector, which implements the abstract methods.

> Create an abstract base class, ASelector, with two abstract methods called selectorRange and selectorValue as follows:
>
> 1. the selectorRange method requires two parameters that define the integer range of possible values from min to max (inclusive) with the following signature
>      public abstract void selectorRange( int min, int max );
> 2. the selectorValue method returns a randomly generated value in the range from min to max (inclusive) and has the following signature
>      public abstract int selectorValue( );
>
> Create a concrete class, Selector, that implements ASelector with appropriate code to implement both methods.

So far I have:

```
public class Selector extends ASelector {

 @Override
    public void selectorRange(int min, int max) {
       min = 1;
       max = 10;  
    }

    @Override
    public int selectorValue(int min, int max) {

         Random r = new Random();
         int randomNumber = r.nextInt(max - min) + min;

         return randomNumber;

    }
}
```

But the error I am getting is with Selector in the method header. It says I have not implemented the abstract methods, yet I have? Or I think I have. Any help would be appreciated.

My ASelector class:

```
public abstract class ASelector {

    public abstract void selectorRange(int min, int max);
    public abstract int selectorValue();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't affect the problem you describe, but `min = 1; max = 10;` simply overwrites the parameter values in `selectorRange`; this has no useful effect.

Comment: Please show your `ASelector` class.

Comment: `public abstract int selectorValue( )` in the spec is not the same as `public int selectorValue(int min, int max) {` in your code.

Comment: The ASelector class is as follows:

Public abstract class ASelector {
 public abstract void selectorRange(int min, int max);
    public abstract int selectorValue();
}

Comment: You are not overriding the abstract method selectorValue(); you are actually trying to overload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class selector you should store the max and min number

```
     int max;
     int min;
```

Then your selectorValue code should look like this:

```
      public int selectorValue(){
          Random r = new Random();
          int randomNumber = r.nextInt(this.max - this.min) + min;
          return randomNumber;
        }
```

What happens is that java allows overload of methods, this means, you can create methods with the same name and different input atrributes and they will be different. This means that  `public int selectorValue()` is different form`public int selectorValue(int min, int max)`, so the method is not implemented.

As a consequence of storing max and min in the Selector your selectorRange should be like this:

```
    public void selectorRange(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;  
    }
```

This will set your internal min and max variables to the value of the parameters min and max

Comment: According to what you described it just acts lke a setter.

Comment: Ahhhh i get it now. Thanks so much mate.

Comment: You re wellcome :)

Comment: So when writing a test harness for this class? How would that look in the main method? Sorry for all the questions, I'm new to programming

Comment: First you should add a constructor like `public selectorRange(int max, int min)` with basically the same code as selectorRange, or `public selectorRange()` and the set default values. As for the tester simply create an object and do some operations using all the methods

Comment: It's set out like

 private void doPart1() {
        StdOut.println("Part1 started\n");
        
        
        
        
        
        StdOut.println("\nPart1 completed");
        StdOut.println("==============================================\n");
    }
So where would this constructor go?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `ASelector` defines

```
public abstract int selectorValue();
```

But you implement

```
public abstract int selectorValue(int min, int max);
```